# Lower bounds of kappa class functions

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, stability

I saw in the paper "Smooth Satabilization Implies Coprime Factorization" of
Eduardo Sontag the following argument: Given a smooth map $a:\mathbb{R}
^{n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{+}$, let $\rho$ be any smooth function of class
$\mathcal{K}_{\infty}$ such that
$\lim_{\xi\rightarrow\infty}a\left(  \xi\right)  \rho\left(  \left\Vert
\xi\right\Vert \right)  =+\infty$. 
It is claimed that $\rho$ exists. Let $\alpha_{3}^{\ast}$ be any smooth
function of class $\mathcal{K}_{\infty}$ so that

$
\alpha_{3}^{\ast}\left(  s\right)  \leq\inf\left\{  a\left(  \xi\right)
\rho\left(  \left\Vert \xi\right\Vert \right)  :\left\Vert \xi\right\Vert
=s\right\}
$

for all $s\geq0$.

My main concern is on the existence of such $\alpha_{3}^{\ast
}\in\mathcal{K}_{\infty}$ because a positive-definite function is not always
lower-bounded by a function in the class $\mathcal{K}_{\infty}$. This is used
in that paper to make the following boundedness:

$-a\left(  \xi\right)  \rho\left(  \left\Vert \xi\right\Vert \right)
\leq-\alpha_{3}^{\ast}\left(  \left\Vert \xi\right\Vert \right)$